# How to access all menu items from onoptionsitemselected

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu, menuitem

I have a `Menu` attached to `Toolbar` and two `MenuItems`. They can also be checked or unchecked. When I select item "0", item "1" should became unchecked and vice-versa. But I cannot access any other menu items except selected one inside the `onOptionsItemSelected()` function. Is there any way to access menu items outside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` (from `onCreate()`, etc)?

I tried creating public `Menu` variable called "items_type" and assigning existing "menu" to it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Did not work... `items_type.findItem()` still gives `NullPointerException` outside `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
public Menu items_type;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items_type, menu);
        this.items_type=menu;
        return true;
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
items_type.findItem(R.id.<id_here>) // nullpointerexception error, that only works inside onCreateOptionsMenu and nowhere else. Any ideas?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try this method :

```
 private boolean isChecked = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_switch_full_original);
         checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.a, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_switch_full_original:
            isChecked = !item.isChecked();
            item.setChecked(isChecked);
            // your other functionality
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: How can I do something with "item 2" if "item 1" is selected? I also need to set another item unchecked.

Comment: Just add return true; . it will do the rest.

Comment: So, the second item will be unchecked automatically (both items have android:checkable="true")?

Comment: Check this @MaximVoloshin

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenueItem item){
       switch (item.getItemId()){
             case R.id.item1:
                //Do whatever you want to do when user clicks item1
                break;
             case R.id.item2:
                //Do whatever you want to do when user clicks item2
                break;
       }
       return true;
}
```

You can get item id using item.getItemId() and then you can perform whatever you want to do.

Comment: How can I set item 1 unchecked if item 0 is selected?

Comment: Resource IDs will be non-final in Android Gradle Plugin version 5.0, avoid using them in switch case statements